# Select row if column data was not selected

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

How can I selected rows from a table when a column data is different.

Table: id(pk), name, title, book_id, date

I want to get all the rows where book_id is uniq.

Data example:

```
test1, test2, 1, 2015-01-01
test2, test4, 1, 2015-01-02
test2, test3, 1, 2015-01-02
test2, test2, 4, 2015-01-03
test4, test2, 5, 2015-01-04
test5, test2, 5, 2015-01-05
```

Expected output:

```
test1, test2, 1, 2015-01-01
test2, test3, 1, 2015-01-02
test2, test2, 4, 2015-01-03
test4, test2, 5, 2015-01-04
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be done using Postgres' [`distinct on`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) operator:

```
select distinct on (book_id) name, title, bookd_id, date
from the_table
order by book_id, date;
```

This will pick the first row for each `book_id` based on the `date` column.